# Adding tabular report to dashboard in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reporting, lightning-experience, limits, dashboard

As adding a tabular report to the dashboard is not available in lightning experience.

Does any one know the solution for this limitation? Any Appexchange product? any other solution like creating a component & use it in the dashboard?

Thanks in advance,
Shilpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can add a tabular report to the dashboard in lightning experience.
You just have to add the row limit in a tabular report.
Please refer [this](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_rd_dashboards_table.htm) link.

Comment: Link is dead. "row limit tabular report" results don't show how to actually do it. Feel like this is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer just an alternative solution.

Creating the Lightning component, which gives you an ability to display the list of reports & on click of the report the report data will display on the component.

OR another approach can be,

Create a lightnig component which accepts the parameter as sobject name, field names(separated by some symbol), field filters(separated by some symbol) & filter logic. By passing these values at controller side, fetching data as requested & displaying the result on the component.

Once the any of these components are ready, Instead of a dashboard, you can place it on the home page.